# Passing custom fields as parameters in a REST query

Tags: services, 8

I am creating a REST Get request using Services 3.3 module on Drupal 7.15 which should get all the nodes filtered by a custom field field_asset_type

http://sharedrive/?q=rest/node&parameters[field_asset_type]=13

It returns following error
Invalid query provided, double check that the fields and parameters you defined are correct and exist. SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'field_asset_type' in 'where clause'

Kindly tell me how to resolve this problem. The articles on the internet explains how to pass built-in fields which is working but I also need to pass custom fields.

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default functionality only works with node *properties*, not *fields*. Fortunately you can use the [Services Entity API](https://drupal.org/project/services_entity) module to get what you need:

> Integration of Services and Entity API.
>
> You can define an endpoint via Services and publish any entity data relying in Entity API.
>
> This module allows to get entities by properties or fields and also paging and related entities that are defined properly.

Comment: I have custom fields available now but I would also want to filter sub-fields of the custom field. For example I only want field_content['und']['fid'] instead of the whole field_content.

Comment: Your best bet will be to submit a feature request to the module, a topic that broad isn't something we can deal with here I'm afraid

Comment: Well the workaround is to use services_views module which allows a view to be accessed through services module

Comment: Just be careful with that module, it's pretty unstable in my experience.